# Bower installation errors. How do I fix it?

Tags: npm, bower-install

```
$ npm install -g bower
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files
(x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd d:\Cpy Work\Yohaat Work\YOHAAT
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     d:\Cpy Work\Yohaat Work\YOHAAT\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

First, you may be behind a proxy.  That's what `npm` is trying to tell you above in the error message.

`This is most likely not a problem with npm itself 
    npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
    npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. 
    npm ERR! network 
    npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the 
    npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'`

To find your proxy setting you may be able to use this powershell command:

`Windows-R to open the "Run" window
Type powershell and click OK
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -Name ProxyServer
....
ProxyServer    : host:port`

You should see your proxy server displayed below.  Set this in your `npm` configuration with a leading `http://`

`npm config set http_proxy "http://host:port"`

If you have any other problems, please upload your npm-debug.log as a  gist http://gist.github.com? If possible, run npm with at least one `-d` flag to increase the logging level.

There have been a lot of improvements to npm -- especially around conflicts and race conditions during install -- since 1.4.28. Can you try updating your npm installation?

To update npm, run `npm -g install npm@latest`

To update npm on Windows, follow the instructions here: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

Thanks!